# How convert pdf to picture in the react js without large library?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I Want to get uploaded file from user and convert it to the picture in the client , i found  pdfjs-dist and react-pdf , but they have a large size and not optimized for use , and i think they are not tree-shakeable , I appreciate to suggest me a good library or a good way to convert

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2pic it has Unpacked Size of 18.3 kB or https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-jpg provides an api for the same

Comment: thank you so mush @Adarsh , i'll check it